# Why does my java client always return null when I try to read response from a global server?

Tags: java, python

This sends a message to the server which in response is supposed to return "ok". I know this works because I also tried it in python and it worked 100%. But in java I am not able to get the response back.

```
 String host = "(name of global host)";
  s.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, 80));

System.out.println("Connected");

    OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
    bw.write("(insert message to sent to server here)");
    bw.flush(); 

BufferedReader brz = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        String t;
        while((t = brz.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(t);
         }
        brz.close();
s.close();
// The loop doesn't even run because it returns null
```

And here is the python code which works perfectly fine unlike java one

```
     HOST, PORT = "(host name)", 80
 self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.sock.settimeout(10)
    self.wrappedSocket = ssl.wrap_socket(self.sock)

    initial_connection_payload = '(text to send to server)'.encode('UTF-8')

    self.wrappedSocket.connect((HOST, PORT))
    self.wrappedSocket.send(initial_connection_payload)
    response = self.wrappedSocket.recv(16384).decode('UTF-8')
    if "ok" not in response:
        self._log(response, "[!] Could not connect to server: " + response)

    self._log("[+] Connected.")
```

So my question is what am I doing wrong in java? I have even tried other ways of doing this such as printwriter dataoutputstream etc. and even tried reading from scanner or just InputStream alone but nothing works. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you provide the full java code?

Comment: @Crigges This pretty much is the full code. Only thing missing is the class name and the main method which it runs inside of

Comment: Did you try calling `bw.close()` instead of just flushing the stream?

Comment: @MickMnemonic Yes I did but then it wouldn't let me read the data and give me a "socket is closed" error

Comment: I see. What about `s.shutdownOutput()` after the flush?

Comment: @MickMnemonic nope still didn't work

Comment: I mean what object type is `s` `Socket`? `ServerSocket`? How did you create `s`

Comment: @Crigges It's just a Socket. I created it like Socket s = new Socket();

Comment: Just give this one a shot: `Socket s = new Socket("(name of global host)", 80);`
And use the the InputStream and OutputStream directly

Comment: The Java code is *not* the same as the Python code.  I see no Java equivalent of `self.wrappedSocket = ssl.wrap_socket(self.sock)`.  Perhaps you meant to create an [SSLSocket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html) with something like `socket = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket(socket, host, 80, true);`?

Comment: @VGR I tried it with SSLSocket as well but instead of returning null that one just freezes and doesn't return anything.

Comment: @Crigges Just tried it got null again :(

Comment: You can't get null if you are using the streams directly. 
`InputStream.read(byte[] arr)` and OutputStream.write(byte[] arr)

Comment: @Crigges Yea I tried that and it didn't give me null but instead froze and didn't print anything like I told VGR above. here is my method

Comment: @Crigges  private static String getinput(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16384];
        int reading = 0;
        while ((reading = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
            baos.write(buffer, 0, reading);
        }
        baos.flush();
        return  new String(baos.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
    }

Comment: @Crigges  After trying your suggestion it sort of worked and returned 10 but I wanted it to return the "ok" string like it does in python

Comment: Maybe the encoding problem. Try ```OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "utf-8");``` and ```BufferedReader brz = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream(), "utf-8"));```.

Comment: I figured it out. The problem was with the way I was reading the input . Thanks for all the help guys

Comment: Maybe you could self-answer this question to benefit others. Was the problem that the server answer didn't have a line ending?